# Algorithm to determine international calling code from phone number

Tags: ios, parsing, addressbook, phone-number

I'm able to retrieve contact's phone number from the device using Address Book framework on iOS. How can I separate or identify which is country code and which is actual phone number?
Is it possible?

Answer (score -9, accepted):

We cannot identify the country code from the phone number.

Comment: If I have array or database or something and compare two numbers will work irrespective of phone number or zip code or something else. If you see my question, I asked for a solution to find it using Address book framework. And without reading it, you gave -1 rating for my answer........

Comment: Well, the statement "We cannot identify the country code from the phone number." is false.

Comment: as per the question, the answer is correct..... don't you even read what's the question is and whether the answer is relevant to question?

Comment: Downvote stands because future readers should not see the sentence "We cannot identify the country code from the phone number" and believe it. If they see that sentence, they should see a big -1 next to it, to tell them "proceed with caution, not everyone agrees with this." Even after rereading your question several more times, your answer is still false, so I'm still downvoting. You also asked for an algorithm, not an API method.

Answer (score 6):

Country codes are a fairly messy topic but standard enough that with some programmer maintenance you can solve it.

You can identify a country code by its initial subsequence.  Do the following algorithm:

1. Build a simple database - can even store as a flat file and load into a dictionary in memory - of country codes.
2. Recursively from n = 1 to 3, check if the first n digits of the phone number match any country code.  If so, that's your country code.  If it fails by try 3, it's not a valid country code.
3. If you like deal with quasi-ambiguities.  If you ever see overlap between country codes, e.g. if you see "1340" for Virgin Islands, it's because in some probably irrelevant sense it's a subset of the country code "1" for U.S.  Country codes sometimes reflect geopolitical situations and usually this is expressed by splitting the country code to the next digit.  "1" will be the official country code but which is of more interest to you depends on your application.

*Note*: This takes maintenance when thinks like the Soviet Union breakup happen.

---

Now, things get messier when you have to deal with the fact that some #s already have country codes on them and some don't and such.  The only country code I've found in which the country code can also occur as a leading area code is Singapore - I think it was `+65-65...`.  With decent accuracy you can use business logic along the lines of:

- Watch for U.S. number format: (xxx) xxx-xxxx and such.
- Use the fact that only certain digits lengths can occur in given countries.  There are documents on this if you search hard enough.  e.g., all U.S. numbers are length 10, Japanese numbers can be length 9 or 10.  This can give you added information.
- Ignore leading 0's for most countries.  Italy and Ivory Coast are the only two exceptions I've found, these can have valid leading 0's.  Otherwise it's just a local telecom convention for staying within the country, usually.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to create an array of all the country calling codes on wikipedia. Then, when I have a phone number, I try to match the first four digits with one of the country calling codes. If none match, try the first three digits and so on. Eventually I find the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

Country calling codes are fairly easy to detect from phone number.

The first thing you need to do is to parse calling codes into a tree where each digit is representing a branch.

Then, finding a country code is as easy as traversing the tree, digit by digit, until the last branch which is a country code match.

At this moment (July 2016.), the longest country calling code has 5 digits, so your tree should not have more than 5 levels of branches.

Answer (score 0):

After some researches I found this lib which seems to do the work:
https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS

Answer (score 0):

To add to @unobic answer, here's a working code sample you could use to do that without a library in JavaScript (because that's what I do, and needed, don't hate me ^^):

```js
// Get the international dialing code (with region code)
// from a given phone number
const getDialingCode = (phoneNumber) => {
  const maxDialingCodeLength = 5
  const start = phoneNumber
    ?.replace(/^(\+|00)/, "")
    .slice(0, maxDialingCodeLength)
  if (start) {
    const tree = start.split("")
    let testedDialingCode = tree.join("")
    let match = countriesMap.get(testedDialingCode)
    while (!match && tree.length) {
      tree.pop()
      testedDialingCode = tree.join("")
      match = countriesMap.get(testedDialingCode)
    }

    if (match && testedDialingCode) {
      return testedDialingCode
    }
  }
}
```

This requires you to have a countries map, which you can generate from https://gist.github.com/daformat/b3bf879b1df325c77999fdd742f1d63f

by doing the following:

```js
// Because some countries can have multiple regional codes
// we first create a flattened list (still using an array
// for the regional code, though this time of length 1 if any
const flattenedCountries = iso3166_1_countries
  .flatMap((country) => {
    return country.dial_region_codes
      ? country.dial_region_codes.map((dial_region_code) => ({
        ...country,
        dial_region_codes: [dial_region_code]
      }))
      : [country]
  })
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))

// We also build a map to make the prefix lookup easier / cheaper
const countriesMap = new Map(
  flattenedCountries.map((country) => [
    country.dial_country_code +
    (country.dial_region_codes ? country.dial_region_codes.join() : ""),
    country
  ])
)
```

If you need to get the full Country info, you can then use the following to get the entry from the countries map:

```js
const getCountryFromPhoneNumber = (
  phoneNumber
) => {
  const dialingCode = getDialingCode(phoneNumber)
  if (dialingCode) {
    return countriesMap.get(dialingCode)
  }
}
```

You can find a fully working typescript implementation of this here:
https://gist.github.com/daformat/ea94d3be630d2039f479ca774e276578