# Do we have a method to identify if a phone number includes a country code?

Tags: phone-number

As how it is running on our modern smart phones, if we dial a number without a country code, by default it will use the user's current country code. On the contrary, if we dial with a specific country code, our smart phones can identify the country code by itself.

What I want to do is similar to it. If user enter a phone number, I want to know if it includes a country code or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't that many country codes.

The manual way I am doing this in the few occasions I need it is, search on the [webpage](http://countrycode.org) for the first numbers of the phone number I am checking.

I had an app that could change my contacts phone numbers to clean it from country codes, if they are in my country, forgot the name. So it should be possible. Maybe they used a database with the known country codes.

An answer that shows a good way to solve it is: [Algorithm to determine international calling code from phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227400/algorithm-to-determine-international-calling-code-from-phone-number).

More often I need it for cites. I use the same way to determine if there is a city code (of course with another webpage). Because the landline does not need the city code, if I am in the same city, but my mobile phone only knows the country, not the city I am in.

Answer (score 0):

Register a list of country codes with the length of the phone number in a database. E.g. for singapore the country code is 65 and the standard phone number will be a length of 8. Hence, with this your program will first read the first few number of the number and try to match it with the country code. If it matches, count the length of the remaining number. Thus, if both are match, you will know which country does the number belong to.

-KLET

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters a number that conforms the [RFC3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) then yes, you can identify the `+`. However, users resort to RFC3966 format just as often as they conform to [ISO-8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/).

So you're stuck with heuristics and local conventions, see [National conventions for writing telephone numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers). Length is, in general, a good indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Use TrueCaller 
if the number has a country code it will show the name of the country below else give the origin country.